# How to find a ceiling value for objects?

Tags: java, ceil

How can I find the ceiling value for list of objects?

For example,

Lets say I have a class `ComputerProperties` which represents the different hardware properties like `cpuType`, `cpuArchitecture`, `memory`, `gpu` etc   of a computer as variables.

Now this class will be of list `List<ComputerProperties>` to represent the various requirements for different games.

Now, lets say given GTA V and Minecraft gaming hardware requirements, How will I find a particular `ComputerProperties` which can satisfy both requirements?

I don't want to use the traditional `>=` to find the `ComputerProperties` which can satisfy all the requirements, as the size of list `List<ComputerProperties>` might be tending to `n`. 
The gaming hardware requirements given by user  as input is `>1` and tending to `m`.

Or is there any other solution which can solve this faster?

Appreciate any suggestions and insights.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some example code that you already tried.

Comment: How about sorting the list by most critical requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by "tending to n"? Note that you can't use `>=` on objects anyway...

Comment: I don't think you'll run into performance problems with this. Even with hundreds of games and tens of properties.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to filter according to some predicate the List? If this is what you wish to achieve you should check guava Collections2 api filter method?

Comment: Using Java 8 filtering is a nice option: http://java.dzone.com/articles/extracting-elements-java

Comment: @PetteriHietavirta: How to find the most critical requirement? Wouldn't that itself be an another problem to solve?

Comment: @Thilo: I'm afraid I'm not following your answer. I would be having two `List` of size n and m , one for game requirement and another for computer properties. Iterating and comparing them would result in better performance?

Comment: Iterating over a list of 200 elements, calling 2000 getters and doing 2000 comparisons is not going to be noticeable to users.

Comment: @alfasin : This looks promising. I will take a look

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you probably want to do something like this:

```
List<CpuType> cpuTypeList = new ArrayList<CpuType>();
List<Memory> memoryList = new ArrayList<Memory>();
// other properties 

for (ComputerProperties properties : listOfProperties) {
    cpuTypeList.add(properties.getCpuType());
    memoryList.add(properties.getMemory());
    // other properties    
}

CpuType mostCriticalCpuType = Collections.max(cpuTypeList);
Memory mostCriticalMemory = Collections.max(memoryList);
// other properties
```